# Loading C# DLL in Delphi does not find dependent library DLL

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, .net-4.5, delphi-7

I have written a small interop DLL in C# to be used by Delphi (not COM).
I am using `iTextSharp` to produce PDF files.
The C# DLL is basically really simple:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {        
        [DllExport("Test1", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static void Test1()
        {
            System.IO.FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\x.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            Document document = new Document();
            document.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
            document.Open();
            document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
            document.Close();
            writer.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }
    }        
}
```

And Delphi host application code (which located in a different folder):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
type
  TDLLProc = procedure; stdcall;
var
  DLLModule: HMODULE;
  DLLProc: TDLLProc;
begin
  // SetCurrentDir('G:\Projects\Test\ClassLibrary1\bin\x86\Release');
  DLLModule := LoadLibrary('G:\Projects\Test\ClassLibrary1\bin\x86\Release\ClassLibrary1.dll');
  if DLLModule = 0 then RaiseLastWin32Error;
  DLLProc := GetProcAddress(DLLModule, 'Test1');  
  if @DLLProc = nil then RaiseLastWin32Error;
  DLLProc(); // external exception E0434352
end;
```

The problem is that calling the method raises `external exception E0434352` because for some reason the C# DLL can't find `itextsharp.dll`.

If I copy `itextsharp.dll` to the `Project1.exe` directory all works well.
If I copy `Project1.exe` to the `'G:\Projects\Test\ClassLibrary1\bin\x86\Release\` all works well.

I don't want the `ClassLibrary1.dll` and `itextsharp.dll` to be placed in my EXE program directory, but use them from their own directories.

I have tried to explicitly set `SetCurrentDirecory`, also tried `SetDllDirectory`, also tried `LoadLibraryEx`. nothing helps.

Seems that even if I place the `itextsharp.dll` DLL (just for testing) in the `C:\Windows` directory, I get the same exception!

What can I do to solve this problem?

---

**EDIT:** A possible solution (twisted IMHO) after looking at [Loading .NET Assemblies out of Seperate Folders](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/dec/12/loading-net-assemblies-out-of-seperate-folders) suggested by @Peter Wolf in the comment if to use `System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom` to load the `itextsharp.dll` assmbly and access each of its classes/methods/members/etc via reflection. i.e.

```
[DllExport("Test1", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static void Test1()
{
    var asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(@"G:\Projects\Test\ClassLibrary1\bin\x86\Release\itextsharp.dll");
    Type tDocument = asm.GetType("iTextSharp.text.Document", true, true);
    dynamic document = Activator.CreateInstance(tDocument);
    Type tPageSize = asm.GetType("iTextSharp.text.PageSize", true, true);
    tPageSize.GetMethod("GetRectangle");
    // ETC... ETC... ETC...
}
```

This actually works, However this looks insane to me! 
Ruining a perfectly simple and good C# code just to be able to do that.
I just can't believe there isn't a **normal** way to load a C# DLL that is located in a different folder than my host Delphi application.

Is there a native/normal and straight forward way to do this without the reflection???

Comment: Maybe this article can help: [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies). See sections about locating assemblies through codebases and probing.

Comment: You can also find some valuable information in blog post [Loading .NET Assemblies out of Seperate Folders](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/dec/12/loading-net-assemblies-out-of-seperate-folders) by Rick Strahl.

Comment: @PeterWolf, Thanks. so if understand correctly the only option I have to use `Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom` and the access each class/method/enum etc via reflection? surely this is insane for my purpose :(

Comment: Not quite. There are many options as you can read in Rick's article. Among them [`AssemblyeResolve`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?view=netframework-4.8) seems to be viable option. I'll try to put a code sample to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook onto assembly resolving mechanism in your C# DLL via [`AssemblyResolve`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?view=netframework-4.8) event. Here you get a chance to locate and load assembly that the .NET runtime is unable to locate by itself. You can install the handler e.g. in class constructor (`Class1` in your case), but this might not be sufficient, if your DLL has some entry points outside of `Class1`. The code to install handler is:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public class Class1
{
    static Class1()
    {
        var dllDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(a => a.FullName == args.Name);
            if (assembly != null)
            {
                return assembly;
            }
            var fileName = args.Name.Split(',')[0] + ".dll";
            var filePath = Path.Combine(dllDirectory, fileName);
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                return Assembly.LoadFile(filePath);
            }
            return null;
        };
    }

    // ...
}
```